# Creating Model without associations

Tags: cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I'm planning to implement some static pages on my current CakePHP site.

These static pages would be stored in a table called `pages` where it will have 2 field; `title` and `content`. Then for example, in the users_controller, I can do a find for the 'Welcome' static entry and set it into the view.

Can I create a model for `pages` without any association because this table in logic does not have any association with the other tables.

Is there any other best way I can implement this with simplicity in mind? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why store them in the database? Why not just write the static pages in the view/pages directory?

If you want to create a model for pages, I would name it something different like "contents". Then you can load the model and pull the data from anywhere:

```
$this->loadModel('Content');
$this->Content->find(...);
```

So the answer is yes, you can create a table that only holds data without any associations.